# how to create Nimbus L&F live template in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nimbus

i want to create a live template in **Intellij IDEA** to add **Nimbus Look and Feel** in my Code when use **"nmbs+Tab"** abbreviation.

here is the code :

```
try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CURRENT.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CURRENT.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CURRENT.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CURRENT.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

because this live template is based on current class name to work correctly,
the problem is ***how can i get and replace current class name with the "CURRENT" word in the code***?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the live template and paste your code into it, but replace `CURRENT` with `$CURRENT$`. Once you've done this, the `Edit Variables` option becomes available. Then, you should click this. You want to define an expression, such as `className()` for you `$CURRENT$` variable.

The whole process is described in the [IntelliJ documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/edit-template-variables-dialog.html).